# Compare two hashmaps of hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two hash map of hashmaps. for an Instance let,

`Hashmap map1 = 
key : mapview Value : {backgroundimage=character varying, mapviewname=character varying, mapviewid=character}
key : am_mypage_template_mgs Value : {resourceid=integer, pageid=integer}
key : am_tomcatinfo Value : {resourceid=bigint, url=character varying, sslenabled=character varying}`

And
`Hashmap map2 = 
key : mapview Value : {backgroundimage=character varying, mapviewname=character varying, mapviewid=integer}
key : am_mypage_template_mgs Value : {resourceid=integer}`
I have to compare these two and find which keys from map1 are missing in map2. If the keys are present I have to compare the innermap and compare the keys of map1's innermap with map2's innermap. If the keys are present I have to compare the values corressponding to the innermap of map1 with map2.
My code is,

```
map1.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        if (map2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(map2.get(entry.getKey()))) {
                count++;
            } else {
                entry.getValue().entrySet().forEach(inside_entry->{
                if(map2.get(entry.getKey()).containsKey(inside_entry.getKey())) {

                    Map<String, String> n = new  HashMap<String, String>();
                    n.putAll(map2.get(entry.getKey()));
                    if((inside_entry.getValue()).equals(map2.get(n))){

                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Tablename1 : "+ entry.getKey() +" Key :"+inside_entry.getKey()+" value : "+inside_entry.getValue());
                    }
                }
                });
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("\"" + entry.getKey() + "\" entire table is not found");
        }
    });
```

My Output should be like this,

```
key am_tomcatinfo in map1 missing in map2 
In am_mypage_template_mgs, pageid in map1 is missing in map2
In mapview, mapviewid=character in map1 is not equal to mapviewid=integer in map2
```

What should I do?

Comment: try below link : https://www.baeldung.com/java-compare-hashmaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, a direct way is to use `forEach()` (not `entrySet().forEach()`) of both maps for comparing keys and values as follows:

```
map1.forEach((k0, v0) -> {
    if (!map2.containsKey(k0)) {
        System.out.println(String.format("key %s in map1 missing in map2", k0));
    } else {
        v0.forEach((k1, v1) -> {
            if (!map2.get(k0).containsKey(k1)) {
                System.out.println(String.format("In %s, %s in map1 is missing in map2", k0, k1));
            } else {
                if (!v1.equals(map2.get(k0).get(k1))) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("In %s, %s=%s in map1 is not equal to %s=%s in map2", k0, k1, v1, k1, map2.get(k0).get(k1)));
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And the console output is

> In am_mypage_template_mgs, pageid in map1 is missing in map2
>     key am_tomcatinfo in map1 missing in map2
>     In mapview, mapviewid=character in map1 is not equal to mapviewid=integer in map2